# Increase height of a UIView in tableView dynamically

Tags: ios, swift4, nslayoutconstraint

[image]

Let me explain my problem from the above reference image:

**1** I have taken a tableView with 1 dynamic cell and two views above the cell and below it not exactly as a header and footer view, just drag two views inside tableView.

**2**  You can see hierarchy from the image attached.

**3** I have 2 address label from which data is coming from API response. The address label has no fixed number of lines, it can be 2, 3 or any.

**

> Problem:

** I want to increase the height of the view dynamically but the constraints are not accessible. How can I manage it?

Answer (score 1):

I achieve this by taking a different cell in UItableView and passing the height as UITableViewAutomatic Dimension. [Solved Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMT6W.png)